# Aggregate CTE and Update Query

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update, aggregate-functions, common-table-expression

I have studied a number of aggregate and CTE post but have not found a solution for updating a minumum value from a CTE to an additional (non-CTE) outside table.  This is using SQL 2008 (Microsoft managment studio).  I am combining dates from an appointment table, dates for services from a billing table, and then cross checking those with a field in a patient table.  If that field called New Patient Date is blank, I want to update it with the earliest date from the other two tables.  They all joined on a common ID called chart or chart number. Here is the code...Any insights?

```
WITH New_Patients (chart_nbr, First_Visit)
  AS
  ( SELECT A.[Chart], MIN(A.[Appt Date])
      FROM Appointment AS A, Patient AS P
      WHERE A.[Chart] = P.[Chart Number]
        AND A.[Appt Date] IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY A.[Chart]

   UNION

   SELECT BD.[Chart], MIN(BD.[Service Date 1])
    FROM [Billing Detail] AS BD, Patient AS P 
    WHERE BD.[Chart] = P.[Chart Number]
      AND [Transaction Code] IN 
         ('99201', '99202', '99203', '99204', '99205', '99211', '99212', '99213', 
         '99214', '99215', '99241', '99242', '99243', '99244', '97001', '97002')
      AND BD.[Service Date 1] IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY BD.[Chart]

   UNION

   SELECT P.[Chart Number], P.[New Patient Date]
     FROM Patient AS P
     GROUP BY P.[New Patient Date], P.[Chart Number]  )

UPDATE [Patient]    
SET Patient.[New Patient Date]=MIN(First_Visit)
FROM Patient AS P, New_Patients AS NP
WHERE P.[Chart Number] = NP.chart_nbr
    AND P.[New Patient Date]IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Cheers, if my understanding is correct, I would solve the issue as follows:

```
   WITH New_Patients (chart_nbr, First_Visit)
  AS
  ( SELECT A.[Chart] as chart_nbr, MIN(A.[Appt Date]) as First_Visit
      FROM Appointment AS A, Patient AS P
      WHERE A.[Chart] = P.[Chart Number]
        AND A.[Appt Date] IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY A.[Chart]
   UNION
   SELECT BD.[Chart], MIN(BD.[Service Date 1])
    FROM [Billing Detail] AS BD, Patient AS P 
    WHERE BD.[Chart] = P.[Chart Number]
      AND [Transaction Code] IN 
         ('99201', '99202', '99203', '99204', '99205', '99211', '99212', '99213', 
         '99214', '99215', '99241', '99242', '99243', '99244', '97001', '97002')
      AND BD.[Service Date 1] IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY BD.[Chart]
   UNION
   SELECT P.[Chart Number], P.[New Patient Date]
     FROM Patient AS P
     GROUP BY P.[New Patient Date], P.[Chart Number]  
 )
UPDATE P SET P.[New Patient Date] = ISNULL(P.[New Patient Date], MIN(NP_group.First_Visit))
from [Patient] P 
left join 
(   
    select min[First_date) as First_Visit, chart_nbr
        from New_Patients 
            group by chart_nbr

) NP_group ON P.[Chart Number] = NP_group.chart_nbr
```

WITH part remained the same, UPDATE part is slightly modified. In subquery you get minimum date across CTE table, then update where is applicable (ISNULL conditioning).